# How do I access an array stored in a .js file from a ReactJs .html file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, import, export

Okay, I've tried to figure this one out on my own and I just can't. I'm making a loot logging web app for a game I play online. The web app is hosted on pythonanywhere. It's coded in ReactJS in the main html file entirely so no databases or anything like that. I store loot tables for different monsters in an array like

```
var monsterName = [
    ["item 1 name", [#,#,#], id],
    ["item 2 name", [#], id]
    ];
```

Etc... The loot arrays are a lot longer than that but you get the idea. I had the code working properly to use these arrays for grabbing item names and image paths and all. I figured if I was going to add more monsters now that my code worked, I should relocate these arrays to a separate file. I called this file 'droptables.js'. I saved it in the same directory as the main html file so it would be easy to find it. I then named an array in the main html script tags (where all of the Reactjs code is) like this

```
lootTable = monsterName;
```

I tried and tried to use various methods to export it from the .js file and import it into the html file, and none work.

```
import monsterName from './droptables.js';
```

coupled with

```
exports.monsterName = [array info]
```

I tried

```
module.exports = monsterName;
export default monsterName;
```

I tried importing in the header of the html instead like

```
<script src="./droptables.js" />
```

I haven't listed every attempt here because I tried several different paths too thinking maybe that was it

```
'/droptables.js'
'droptables.js'
'droptables'
'/templates/droptables.js'
```

You get the idea. Hopefully someone out there can help me figure this out. It's one of the last roadblocks I have before my app is complete at least in the base functionality sense and it's driving me crazy that I can't get this solved. Thank you for any help!

EDIT: I added the beginning of my HTML/React sheet below so you can see what it looks like and where I'm trying to import.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>LootLogger Webapp 1.1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <script src="react url"></script>
    <script src="react url"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-
    core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

    import abyssalDemon from './droptables.js';
    var monsterLoot = abyssalDemon;

    var LootEntry = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>{this.props.children}</div>
            );
        }
    });
```

As you can see, abyssalDemon is what I named my array in the other javascript file, monsterLoot is the array I use in the actual code here on the html sheet, so I need monsterLoot to equal abyssalDemon from the other js file for everything to work. LootEntry is just the first React component I make, it's an entry in the list of loots the user has logged.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing everything (in droptables.js) inside an immediately invoked function?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't exactly understand what you mean. I'll update with the full beginning of my code.

Comment: Immediately-invoked function is literally what it is. an example would be `(function hi() { console.log("hi"); })()`. Notice the parentheses right after the function declaration. It will make the variable inside droptable.js accessible within the html document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to do it a different way without using required and instead using Jquery. I modified my original html document like the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>LootLogger Webapp 1.1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <script src="react url"></script>
    <script src="react url"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-
    core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/static/javascript/droptables.js'>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var monsterLoot = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function () {
    monsterLoot = AbyssalDemon;
    });
</script>

<script type="text/babel">

    var LootEntry = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>{this.props.children}</div>
            );
        }
    });
```

I added the import of Jquery in the header  tags. I also added a  tag in my body to reference my droptables.js file. Finally, I added a the Jquery function to make my monsterLoot array equal to the AbyssalDemon array from the external js file. I did this in a document ready function because I believe part of my problem was my page was trying to generate my buttons before the monsterLoot array had been imported so it was throwing an error because the array was undefined. At least that's my guess. It works now though!